# metaMS and xcms for R Studio suddenly throwing errors

Tags: r

I've been working with a script that utilizes metaMS and xcms to look at GCMS CDF files. The script, I'm assuming, is fine, because I literally only changed a database file before it started throwing errors.

I have since changed the database file back to what it was before, tried earlier iterations of the script, reinstalled both R and R studio and subsequently reinstalling BiocManager to reinstall metaMS and xcms, but to no avail.

It's having particular trouble with MSnbase and rtools, saying I need rtools to install packages, but that rtools is not compatible with my version of R (I'm using R 3.6 and R Studio 1.2.1335 - I am open to updating but this often causes issues with certain packages so I'm trying to avoid that).

I even tried to run as administrator to reinstall, and it's still not working.

I'm including images of the various errors I've encountered.

If you have ANY ideas I am open to them. I am at a complete loss.

P.S. I am definitely installing the dependencies. I've tried installing via command line and through the installer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Laura - can you install the latest version of R (4.0.1) and try it with that?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion! I had to go through the computer completely (it was previously a shared computer) and it turned out that someone had saved the program files for R in several different places with several different types of permissions. I simply had to purge the computer and re-install everything.

Comment: Oof,  that is not an ideal situation.  Glad to hear you got it sorted out!